# Is there a class that can represent all entities in symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony

I'm refactoring my form handlers to store common tasks in an `abstract class`.

I encounter problems with type-hinting.

I create an `abstract method` in my parent class which is called when form is valid :

```
/**
 * Action to perform if form is valid
 */
public abstract function onSuccess($data);
```

The parameter `$data` contains the new/modified entity, so the class of this object is different for all implementations of the `abstract class`.

With the previous version of `onSuccess` prototype, I'm not able to declare entity type in my children like this :

```
public function onSuccess(Playlist $playlist) { ... }
```

So is there a base class I can use for type-hinting in `abstract class` which can represente all entity and permit me to use type-hinting in child class.

```
public abstract function onSuccess(??? $data);
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds to me as if you need to use an [Interface](http://php.net/interface), then you can type hint against that.

Comment: I agree but I was hoping this interface already exists in the orm layer.

Comment: No, but it will be trivial for you to create it.